# Regular Expression currency format

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have a string that contains a currency with text. I should get the currency in a float format.

Examples on how the conversion should work

```
Cash € 1,00          => 1.00
Cash € 10,00         => 10.00
Cash $ 10.00         => 10.00
Maestro € 1,0000     => 1.0000
Visa € 1.000,00      => 1000.00
Cash € 1.000.000,00  => 1000000.00
Cash $ 1,000,000.00  => 1000000.00
```

For now I do it in 2 steps. The first expression filters out only `0-9` `.` and `,`

```
var regex = /(\d|\.|,)/g
value = value.match(regex).join('');
```

I'm struggling with my second regex

```
var regex2 = /(\.|,)(?=.*(\.|,))/g;
```

This one matches every dot or comma except the last one.

How can I use this second regex to do the inverse? So instead of matching the `.` and `,`, match everything else but those.

Comment: From what I understood you just need to write: `/([0-9]+)/g`...

Comment: With that expression i lose my comma

Comment: your strings is all in this format?

Comment: My strings contain words + currency sign + an amount in american / european notation. All in no particular order

Comment: Why don't you use your second regex to replace all matched dots or commas with an empty string and in a third step replace comma with dot?

Comment: Sidenote: you can write `/(\d|\.|,)/` as `/[\d.,]/`

Comment: Whats the expected result of using this 2nd regex? Can you describe it like the first overview you made like `Cash € 1,00          => 1.00`

Comment: Are you sure you want Maestro € 1,0000     => 1.0000 and not 10000?

Answer (score 0):

Allright i took a slightly different approach to it.

I think some people in the comments misunderstood me, The strings I receive can be either written in American notation or European notation. Example:

```
American: 1,345.20 = European 1.345,20
```

the `,` and `.` can be used both as thousands separator or decimal separator

I take all the number groups and then join them except the last one. Then I put a dot in between and add the last one to my float.

```js
var regex = /([0-9]+)/g;
var arrValues = value.match(regex);
if(arrValues.length == 1) value.push(0);
var newValue = parseFloat(_.initial(arrValues).join('') + '.' + _.last(arrValues));
```

The if statement is to prevent a number without `,` or `.` to be converted into `0.value` like `10 => 0.10`

Sidenote: i use [lodash](https://lodash.com) to do some stuff.